# Unhandled Exception when Inserting Data Into Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, insert

I am trying to insert data into a database when I run into this unhandled exception:

> An exception of type `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` occurred in `System.Data.dll` but was not handled in user code

This is the code

```
public void addEvent(String username, int id, String date)
{
    String conString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\SleekBook\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\WebSites\\WebSite2\\App_Data\\Database.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        String sqlStringS = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, EventID, Date) VALUES (@Username, @EventID, @Date)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStringS);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EventID", id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

As you can see I try to insert two strings and an int.

The error occurs on:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> Additional information: Invalid column name 'EventID'.
>   Invalid column name 'Date'.

The column names are correct.

Comment: "The column names are correct." They are not.

Comment: Can you show us the table structure?

Comment: I am terribly sorry I was stuck on it for a few hours, and I did not even notice the Table name was wrong.

Comment: BTW, `Date` is not the greatest name for a column

Comment: ..because `Date` is usually a reserved word which may confuse the parser. Also, it is too general. Better to use `Created_Date`, or `Approved_Date` or `Event_Date` which also explains somewhat what the value represents.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest these:

- Didn't forget table prefix like `dbo.TableName`.
- Always use `[` and `]` for all names like `[prefix].[tablename].[fieldname]`

For Example a better query for this question is:

```
String sqlStringS = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Users] ([Username], [EventID], [Date]) VALUES (@Username, @EventID, @Date)";
```